# GitHub Markdown renders SVG files incorrectly, has [] next to them

Tags: github, markdown

On my GitHub Page (https://github.com/mv5903), you can see that the icons next to the programming languages have `[]` next to them. I have attached the markdown code that refers to that part of the file.

```
### Connect With Me:

[<img align="left" alt="kwikmatt.ddns.net" width="22px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iconic/open-iconic/master/svg/globe.svg" />][website]
[<img align="left" alt="kwikmatt | YouTube" width="22px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/youtube.svg" />][youtube]
[<img align="left" alt="kwikmatt | Twitter" width="22px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/twitter.svg" />][twitter]
[<img align="left" alt="kwikmatt | Instagram" width="22px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/instagram.svg" />][instagram]
[<img align="left" alt="kwikmatt | Facebook" width="22px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/facebook.svg" />][facebook]
[<img align="left" alt="kwikmatt | Stack Overflow" width="22px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/stackoverflow.svg" />][stack]
[<img align="left" alt="kwikmatt | Linkedin" width="22px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/linkedin.svg" />][linkedin]

<br />

### Languages/Programs I'm Familiar With:

[<img align="left" alt="Java" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/java.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="Eclipse" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/eclipseide.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="C" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/c.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="C#" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/csharp.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="C++" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/cplusplus.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="R" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/r.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="JQuery" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/jquery.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="PHP" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/php.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="Python" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/python.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="HTML5" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/html5.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="CSS3" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/css3.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="JavaScript" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/javascript.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="Git" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/git.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="GitHub" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/github.svg" />]
[<img align="left" alt="Visual Studio" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/visualstudio.svg" />]

<br />
<br />
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source text you are providing to GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but try simply taking the leading `[` and trailing `]` out for each icon:

```
### Languages/Programs I'm Familiar With:

<img align="left" alt="Java" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/java.svg" />
<img align="left" alt="Eclipse" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/eclipseide.svg" />
<img align="left" alt="C" width="26px" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v3/icons/c.svg" />
...
```

Those brackets aren't doing anything useful.